# Keep installed packages between patch updates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

Using *pyenv* is there a way to keep packages installed for a version when upgrading to a different patch release? E.g. suppose I installed *IPython* with `3.11.1` and now am installing `3.11.2`, but want to keep the IPython. My own guess is it's impossible as there are different directories for different versions at a higher level not just minor releases, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you considered creating a new virtual environment and pinning your package versions into a "traditional" `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I know and use _virtual envs_ (with pipenv mostly). What I'm looking for is a bit more complex and probably impossible. Simply put I want to install packages for `3.11` and not `3.11.1` and this way (uninstalling and) updating to `3.11.2` will preserve my installed packages.